# GWT - Add and remove nodes in celltree

Tags: gwt, addition

Here I have an complete and very easy example to dynamically add/remove
nodes to an celltree. My example is not working very well. It seems there
is an refresh problem. Only closing/expanding the nodes will show the correct
result. I also did not found any answer in this forum which fits to this problem.
Maybe somebody can try my example and tell me where the problem is.
Any other hint is also very appreciated.

Greetings, Marco

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.SingleSelectionModel;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.TreeViewModel;

public class MyCelltreeTest implements EntryPoint {
  private AbsolutePanel absolutePanel;
  private CellTree cellTree;
  private Button btnAdd;
  private Button btnRemove;
  private MyTreeModel myTreeModel;
  private SingleSelectionModel<MyNode> selectionModelCellTree = null;

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.add(getAbsolutePanel(), 0, 0);
  }

  private AbsolutePanel getAbsolutePanel() {
    if (absolutePanel == null) {
      absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
      absolutePanel.setSize("612px", "482px");
      absolutePanel.add(getCellTree(), 0, 0);
      absolutePanel.add(getBtnAdd(), 265, 428);
      absolutePanel.add(getBtnRemove(), 336, 428);
    }
    return absolutePanel;
  }

  private CellTree getCellTree() {
    if (cellTree == null) {
      myTreeModel = new MyTreeModel();
      cellTree = new CellTree(myTreeModel, null);
      cellTree.setSize("285px", "401px");
    }
    return cellTree;
  }

  private Button getBtnAdd() {
    if (btnAdd == null) {
      btnAdd = new Button("Add");
      btnAdd.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

          MyNode node =   selectionModelCellTree.getSelectedObject();
          if(node != null)
            myTreeModel.addNew(node, "Bla");
        }
      });
    }
    return btnAdd;
  }

  private Button getBtnRemove() {
    if (btnRemove == null) {
      btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
      btnRemove.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
          MyNode node = selectionModelCellTree.getSelectedObject();
          if(node != null)
            myTreeModel.remove(node);
        }
      });
    }
    return btnRemove;
  }

  public class MyNode {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<MyNode> childs; //nodes childrens
    private MyNode parent; //track internal parent
    private MyCell cell; //for refresh - reference to visual component

    public MyNode(String name) {
      super();
      parent = null;
      this.name = name;
      childs = new ArrayList<MyNode>();
    }

    public void addSubMenu(MyNode m) {
      m.parent = this;
      childs.add(m);
    }

    public void removeMenu(MyNode m) {

      m.getParent().childs.remove(m);
    }

    public boolean hasChildrens() {
      return childs.size()>0;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyNode> getList() {
      return childs;
    }

    public MyNode getParent() {
      return parent;
    }

    public void setCell(MyCell cell) {
      this.cell = cell;
    }

    public void refresh() {
      if(parent!=null) {
        parent.refresh();
      }
      if (cell!=null) {
        cell.refresh(); //refresh tree
      }
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  public class MyTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {
    private MyNode officialRoot; //default not dynamic
    private MyNode studentRoot; //default not dynamic
    private MyNode testRoot; //default not dynamic
    private MyNode root;

    public MyNode getRoot() { // to set CellTree root
      return root;
    }

    public MyTreeModel() {
      selectionModelCellTree = new SingleSelectionModel<MyNode>();
      root = new MyNode("root");
      // Default items
      officialRoot = new MyNode("Cat"); //some basic static data
      studentRoot = new MyNode("Dog");
      testRoot = new MyNode("Fish");
      root.addSubMenu(officialRoot);
      root.addSubMenu(studentRoot);
      root.addSubMenu(testRoot);
    }

    //example of add add logic
    public void addNew(MyNode myparent, String name) {
      myparent.addSubMenu(new MyNode(name));
      myparent.refresh(); //HERE refresh tree
    }
    public void remove(MyNode objToRemove) {

      objToRemove.removeMenu(objToRemove);
      objToRemove.refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
      ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataProvider;
      MyNode myValue = null;
      if (value == null) { // root is not set
        dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyNode>(root.getList());
      } else {
        myValue = (MyNode) value;
        dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyNode>(myValue.getList());
      }
      MyCell cell = new MyCell(dataProvider); //HERE Add reference
      if (myValue != null)
        myValue.setCell(cell);
      return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyNode>(dataProvider, cell, selectionModelCellTree, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
      if (value instanceof MyNode) {
        MyNode t = (MyNode) value;
        if (!t.hasChildrens())
          return true;
        return false;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  public class MyCell extends AbstractCell<MyNode> {
    ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataProvider; //for refresh

    public MyCell(ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataProvider) {
      super();
      this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
    public void refresh() {
      dataProvider.refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, MyNode value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
      if (value == null) {
        return;
      }
      sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

---

Thanks Ümit for your explanation.
I tried the close-reopen version.
I have replaced my refresh method with the methods below.
Adding is working but removing not. 
Very strange the whole topic. I'm very suprised that these basic
functions are not really supported by GWT.
Can somebody give me more help to run a real working example.

```
    public void refresh() {

         closeReopenTreeNodes(cellTree.getRootTreeNode());
    }

    private void closeReopenTreeNodes(TreeNode node) {
        if(node == null) {
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {

             if(node.getChildValue(i).equals(this)){

                 if(node.getParent() != null){

                     node.getParent().setChildOpen(i, false);
                     //node.getParent().setChildOpen(i, true);
                 }

                 node.setChildOpen(i, false);
                 node.setChildOpen(i, true);
             }               
             TreeNode child = node.setChildOpen(i, node.isChildOpen(i));
             closeReopenTreeNodes(child);
        }
    }
```

Here my third try:
This way is recommended by gwt-commiter. 
Please see following issue:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7160

Current status: 
* Adding is possible
* Removing is possible if not last child!

So, last open point, refresh the tree if last open child!

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.SingleSelectionModel;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.TreeViewModel;

public class MyCelltreeTest2 implements EntryPoint {
    private AbsolutePanel absolutePanel;
    private CellTree cellTree;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private Button btnRemove;
    private MyTreeModel myTreeModel;
    private SingleSelectionModel<MyNode> selectionModelCellTree = null;
    private Map<MyNode, ListDataProvider<MyNode>> mapDataProviders = null;
    private ListDataProvider<MyNode> rootDataProvider = null;

    public void onModuleLoad() {
            RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
            rootPanel.add(getAbsolutePanel(), 0, 0);
    }

    private AbsolutePanel getAbsolutePanel() {
            if (absolutePanel == null) {
                    absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
                    absolutePanel.setSize("612px", "482px");
                    absolutePanel.add(getCellTree(), 0, 0);
                    absolutePanel.add(getBtnAdd(), 265, 428);
                    absolutePanel.add(getBtnRemove(), 336, 428);
            }
            return absolutePanel;
    }
    private CellTree getCellTree() {
            if (cellTree == null) {
                    myTreeModel = new MyTreeModel();
                    cellTree = new CellTree(myTreeModel, null);
                    cellTree.setSize("285px", "401px");
            }
            return cellTree;
    }
    private Button getBtnAdd() {
            if (btnAdd == null) {
                    btnAdd = new Button("Add");
                    btnAdd.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    MyNode node = selectionModelCellTree.getSelectedObject();

                                 myTreeModel.add(node, "Bla");
                            }
                    });
            }
            return btnAdd;
    }
    private Button getBtnRemove() {
            if (btnRemove == null) {
                    btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
                    btnRemove.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                             MyNode node = selectionModelCellTree.getSelectedObject();

                                     myTreeModel.remove(node);
                            }
                    });
            }
            return btnRemove;
    }


    public class MyNode {

        private String name;
        private ArrayList<MyNode> childs; //nodes childrens
        private MyNode parent; //track internal parent


        public MyNode(String name) {
            super();
            parent = null;
            this.name = name;
            childs = new ArrayList<MyNode>();
        }
        public boolean hasChildrens() {
            return childs.size()>0;
        }
        public ArrayList<MyNode> getList() {
            return childs;
        }
        public MyNode getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }      
    }

    public class MyTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {


        public MyTreeModel() {
            selectionModelCellTree = new SingleSelectionModel<MyNode>();
            mapDataProviders = new HashMap<MyCelltreeTest2.MyNode, ListDataProvider<MyNode>>();
        }

        public void add(MyNode myparent, String name) {

            MyNode child = new MyNode(name);

            //root-node
            if(myparent == null){
                    rootDataProvider.getList().add(child);
                    mapDataProviders.put(child, rootDataProvider);
            }
            else{

                    ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataprovider = mapDataProviders.get(myparent);
                    myparent.childs.add(child);
                    child.parent = myparent;
                    dataprovider.refresh();
            }
        }   
        public void remove(MyNode objToRemove) {

            ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataprovider = mapDataProviders.get(objToRemove);
                    dataprovider.getList().remove(objToRemove);
  //                 mapDataProviders.remove(objToRemove);
                    dataprovider.refresh();
                    dataprovider.flush();

                    if(objToRemove.parent != null){
                            ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataproviderParent = mapDataProviders.get(objToRemove.parent);
                            objToRemove.parent.childs.remove(objToRemove);
                            dataproviderParent.refresh();
                            dataproviderParent.flush();
                    }
                    else{
                            rootDataProvider.refresh();
                            rootDataProvider.flush();
                    }       
        } 


        @Override
        public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {

            if (value == null) { // root is not set
             rootDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyNode>(new ArrayList<MyNode>());
                    MyCell cell = new MyCell(); 
   return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyNode>(rootDataProvider, cell,   
  selectionModelCellTree, null);
            } else {
                    MyNode myValue = (MyNode) value;
                ListDataProvider<MyNode> dataProvider = 
                    new ListDataProvider<MyNode>(myValue.childs);
                    MyCell cell = new MyCell(); 
                    for(MyNode currentNode : myValue.childs){
                            mapDataProviders.put(currentNode, dataProvider);
                    }
                return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyNode>(dataProvider, cell,  
              selectionModelCellTree, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
            if (value instanceof MyNode) {
                MyNode t = (MyNode) value;
                if (!t.hasChildrens())
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            return false; 
        }

    }

    public class MyCell extends AbstractCell<MyNode> {
            public MyCell() {
              super();
            }
            @Override
            public void render(Context context, MyNode value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
              if (value == null) {
                return;
              }
              sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has anybody gotten their way around this cleanly? Frustratingly this is closed as designed in GWT issuelist - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7160

Answer (score 5):

This is somehow a known problem with CellTree.
The reason for the refresh problem is that in the `getNodeInfo()` function you create a new `ListDataProvider` instance for each CellTree level.
The CellTree only updates/refreshes itself if you update the items in that `ListDataProvider`. 
I believe that your removeMenu() and addSubMenu() functions add and remove items from the original list stored in your MyNode class but won't update the list in the corresponding ListDataProviders (you can try to check that in debug mode).
The reason why the CellTree is refreshed when you close and re
-open the nodes is because when you re-open the nodes the `getNodeInfo()` is called again and the whole CellTree structure will be constructed again (including the new menu or without the removed one respectively).

There are two possible solutions:

1. Keep a reference for each of the `ListDataProviders` somewhere and call remove/add on that list (although you do that I assume that the items are not really added/removed there).
2. Programatically close all nodes and re-open it.

Both are somehow a PITA to implement. Unfortunately there is no easy way around it.

Comment: Thanks Ümit for your explanation. I tried the close-reopen version.  Adding is working but removing not. Do you have a complete working example for one of your suggested solutions?

Comment: I will post a close-reopen code tomorrow or th day after tomorrow

Comment: Hi Ümit, do you have an example? I still have found no solution for that.

Comment: Has anybody gotten their way around this cleanly? Frustratingly this is closed as designed in GWT issuelist - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7160

Comment: @SSR unfortunately not. I have switched from a CellTree to a normal Tree widget (because I don't have many nodes to display). 
I think probably one has to extend the ``CellTree`` class to implement this feature (maybe even provide a patch for GWT itself)

Answer (score 0):

I just clear the array of objects maintained in my data provider. I do this in `onRangeChanged(final HasData<?> display)`. I guess I don't use a `ListDataProvider` here, I use something extending `AbstractDataProvider<T>` instead.

To add the node add it to your list within the `onRangeChanged()` method and then call `updateRowData()`. You can do this for a delete too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have licked the problem...

Essentially I've extended and subclasses many parts of CellTree and have obtained an almost perfect working example. Too complex to document here, but suffice to say the solution involved using a node class where I stored the data provider within each node.

https://code.google.com/p/updatable-cell-tree/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair enough, but not really practical if you took the time to really look at the answer. The solution isn't something simple enough to include here yeah?