# CellTree suggestion - AsyncDataProvider add/remove/update

Tags: gwt

I have issues with GWT CellTree and at this point, I'm wondering if it's really ready for prime time. Maybe I'm not getting the default use-cases??

Most questions that have seen over the Web so far are related to CRUD operations with a CellTree but using a simple [ListDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html) such as [GWT - Add and remove nodes in celltree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044688/gwt-add-and-remove-nodes-in-celltree).

In my case, I'm populating the nodes of a CellTree using an [AsyncDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html).
The nodes are fetched on-demand using a [RequestFactory](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory) service.

Given a selection, I would like to add child nodes, remove/update the current selection. The GWT TreeViewModel interface is way too basic in my opinion.

From my current understanding, the way to go would be to use a map of DataProviders, keep a reference of the underlying list returned by the remote call and likely a reference to the parent [NodeInfo](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/TreeViewModel.NodeInfo.html) object.

For example to delete the current selection I'd probably do the following:

```
TreeViewModel model = cellTree.getTreeViewModel();
TreeViewModel.NodeInfo nodeInfo = model.getNodeInfo(selectionFromChangeListener);
CustomNodeInfo parent = ((CustomNodeInfo) nodeInfo).getParent();
parent.getUnderLyingNodeListFromDataProvider().remove(selectionFromChangeListener);
// maybe force refresh using dataProvider???
parent.getDataProvider().refreshDisplayAsInRepopulateData()
```

Any better suggestion? It looks like it's going to be a challenging task, unless I'm mistaken... It seems a bit overkill though. In Swing it would be very easy to achieve or even in most other Web Frameworks providing Tree widgets.

Would using the default [Tree](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html) widget and replacing myself the icons with the "loading" image be a more straightforward thing? It looks like the basic Tree allows way more manipulations of nodes as [TreeItems](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html).

Answer (score 1):

The CellTree widget seems to be based on the original code of [FastTree](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/FastTree).

The FastTree already have more or less what I need, without some kind of *setUserObject* method as in a Swing [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#setUserObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

For spinning icons, someone [already investigated](http://markmacumber.net/2009/05/gwt-fasttree-and-a-spinner-icon.html) it in the past.

I guess that for now, I'll switch from CellTree to a customized version of FastTree and [FastTreeItem](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/source/browse/branches/dflorey/tableAddons/src/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/FastTreeItem.java?spec=svn1211&r=1211).

Out of the box ability to have methods such as getParentItem, remove(current node or specific child node)?? Thank you very much sir...

Comment: Switching to the FastTree solved my issues. I ended up implementing myself, the notion of userObject on a custom FastTreeItem. I created my own IDataProvider concept too.


From basic operation to more complex stuff using remote calls, everything is fine...
The catch for remote calls is to ideally provide an initial child count so that the appropriate expand/collapse icon is shown.


In most customizations of the FastTree and FastTreeItems that I have seen, the entire tree is populated lazily, but at once, recursively. In my case, each node is populated only on demand via RequestFactory calls.