# How to properly implement MVP in GWT for a CellTree?

Tags: java, gwt

Imagine I have a class `CellTreeWidget`, which contains a `CellTree`.

I want to write a presenter, which interacts with

1. the `CellTreeWidget` instance and
2. a remote service for getting the data.

The data displayed in the `CellTreeWidget` is a list of items. Each item has a parent item and belongs to a container.

```
public class Container
{
    public List<Item> getItemList();
    public void setItemList(List<Item> aItemList);
}

public class Item
{
    public int getItemId();
    public int getParentItemId();
}
```

There are following processes that involve the presenter:

1. User selects a container (see `Presenter.startEdit` below).
2. User saves the changes made to a container (see `Presenter.save` below).

When the user selects a container, the `CellTreeWidget` must be updated to show the items of the newly selected container.

When the user saves changes made to a container, the presenter must

1. send a save request to the remote service and
2. if the request has been processed correctly, make sure that the items in the tree have been updated.

Step 2 is necessary because the user is able to create new items on the client. When they are saved on the server, their data (primary key) are changed.

To implement this, I've been told to use following approach:

```
public class Presenter
{
    private RemoteService service;
    private View view;
    private ListDataProvider<Item> dataProvider;
    private Container data;

    public Presenter()
    {
        dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Item>(new ItemProvidesKey());
    }
    public void setService(final RemoteService aService) 
    {
        service = aService;
    }
    public void setView(final View aView) 
    {
        view = aView;

        final HasData<Item> dataToDisplay = view.getDisplay();

        if (dataToDisplay != null)
        {
          dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dataToDisplay);
        }
    }
    public void save() {
        List<Item> allPages = new ArrayList<Item>();
        allPages.addAll(dataProvider.getList());
        data.setItemList(allPages);

        service.save(data, new AsyncCallback<ContainerSaveResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ContainerSaveResult result) {
                afterSave(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("Save error: " + caught.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    protected void afterSave(ContainerSaveResult result) 
    {
        for (final Page curItem : dataProvider.getList()) 
        {
            final Integer oldId = curPage.getItemId();
            final Integer newId = result.getNewItemIdsByOldItemIds().get(oldId);

            if (newId != null) 
            {
                curPage.setItemId(newId);
            }
        }

        dataProvider.flush();
    }
    public void startEdit(Container aContainer) 
    {
        data = aContainer;
        if (data != null) 
        {
            view.getDisplay().setRowCount(data.getItemList().size(), true);
            dataProvider.setList(data.getItemList());
        }
    }
}
```

`CellTreeWidget` implements the interface `View`, which is defined like this:

```
public interface View extends IsWidget, HasSelectionChangedHandlers {
  HasData<Item> getDisplay();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I see no obvious way to provide an implementation of method `HasData<Item> getDisplay()` in the `CellTreeWidget` class.

Therefore my question: If you

1. have a tree-like structure, which is
2. displayed in a `CellTree`,
3. can be modified by both on the client (user adds a new item) and
4. on the server (new item is saved in the database and gets a new ID)

and want to implement a clean mechanism for updating the data and the view, how can it be done the right, GWT-style way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Unfortuntely `CellTree` is quite a complex widget and uses entirely different concepts compared to a `CellTable` or a `DataGrid`.
That is also the reason why it doesn't impelement a `HasData` interface as the other CellWidgets.

Futhermore with `CellTree` updating and refreshing its nodes is not really well supported enough out of of the box. There are a couple of workarounds (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7160) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044688/gwt-add-and-remove-nodes-in-celltree)). 
There is also extension of the `CellTree` that tries to fix some of these issues ([Project](https://code.google.com/p/updatable-cell-tree/), [Code](https://code.google.com/p/updatable-cell-tree/source/browse/src/com/google/code/tree/client/UpdatableCellTreeTest.java), [Demo](https://updatable-cell-tree.googlecode.com/git/war/UpdatableCellTreeTest.html)).

I would recommend to first implement your use case with a `CellTree` and later worry about whether it fits with the `MVP` style. I can already tell you that it won't be easy to draw sharp boundaries between `View` and `Presenter` when dealing with a `CellTree`.

### Your use-case

If I understood your use-case correctly, you have a list of `Container` objects (are you using a `CellList` ?) and when you select a specific container you want to show the list of items in a `CellTree` and allow the user to edit and add/remove items.

I will try to highlight the important steps:

1.) Your data-structure doesn't really work nicely with a `CellTree`. You should a reference to the parent and a list of childs from each item:

```
public class Item
{
    public int getItemId();
    public Item getParent();
    public List<Item> getChilds();
}
```

`CellTree` unlike `DataGrid` or `CellTable` uses a `TreeViewModel`.

2.) Define a custom `TreeViewModel`.

```
public class MyCustomTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {

    private final SelectionModel<Item> selectionModel;
    private final ValueUpdater<Item> valueUpdater;

    public MyCustomTreeModel(final SelectionModel<Item> selectionModel, ValueUpdater<Item> valueUpdater) {
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
        this.valueUpdater = valueUpdater;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(final T value) {
        // The root node is the container
        ListDataProvider<Item> = new ListDataProvider<Item>();
        if (value instanceof Container) {
            provider.setList(((Container)value).getItemList();
            return new DefaultNodeInfo<Item>(provider, containerCell, selectionModel,null);
        }
        provider.setList(((Item)value).getChilds());
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<Item>(provider, itemCell, selectionModel, valueUpdater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
        Item item = (Item) value;
        return value != null && item.getChild().size() == 0;
    }
}
```

3.) Instantiate your custom `MyCustomTreeModel` in your `View` and create the `CellTree` with the selected `Container` instance (you can it from the `Presenter` when you select a container:

```
public void onStartEdit(Container container, SelectionModel<Item> selectionModel, ValueUpdater<Item> valueUpdater) {
    CellTree tee = new CellTree(new MyCustomTreeModel(selectionModel,valueUpdater));
}
```

### Summary

Again you will probably run into refreshing issues and you will have to add a `add()` and a `remove()` function to your `TreeViewModel` for adding and removing items.

Check out the linked issues for some workarounds and code and I would recommend to use the extended `CellTree`. If possible use a different Widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it correct that if I used a GWT-based framework, like Vaadin, I wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: AFAIK Vaadin has the same `CellTree` as in `GWT`, so you will run into the same issues. There are 3 solutions: 1.) Look for a third party tree widget (maybe Javascript) and write  wrapper for it. 2.) Use the extending `CellTree` version or 3.) use the standard `CellTree` and use the workarounds.